# C# 2013 Default certificate could not be created. Publish aborting

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to run a .exe that I built in Visual Studio 2013 with C# it will run just fine on the machine I compiled it in. When I try to run the program on different machines I get exception errors.

So I tried to publish the program and I get this error:

> Default certificate could not be created. Publish aborting

If I run the executable from a machine that has Visual Studio on it it works fine.

When I try to create a certificate I get the error

> The Profile for the user is a temporary profile. (exception from
>   HRESULT:0x80090024)

I would like this executable to run at start-up on all Windows 7 student computers in our school.

Answer (score 24):

You need to tell the publisher where to get the certificate from:

1. Go to *Project* → *Properties*
2. Go to the tab named *"Signing"*
3. Check the checkbox labeled *"Sign the ClickOnce manifests"*. This enables the section where you can point to a certificate.
4. Click on the button labeled *"Select From File..."*. In the directory listing, choose a key file (.pfx) and *Open...*.
5. From the step 3, click the button labeled *"More Details..."*. This will display the certificate you've just selected.
6. Click *"Install Certificate"* and follow the prompts.
7. Save and *Publish* your solution.

Comment: How do I create a .pfx file?

Comment: For whatever reason, I had to run VS as an administrator to create the test certificate. Otherwise I received an "Access Denied" message.

Comment: This worked for me. Now I know what that PFX file was for.

Answer (score 14):

Run Visual Studio with administrative rights (*Run as administrator*).

Comment: This solution seemed to be working in VS 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: Same with VS 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Run as administrator. It worked for me (Visual Studio 2017).

Comment: In the context of the original question, Administrator rights on the student computers might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works for me using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition in Windows 10.

Make sure that your account has write access to folder '**C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys**'.

Also make sure your account has write access to the folder where you are creating the key.