# Even with admin rights I cant publish my VB.NET app and get Default certificate could not be created. Publish aborting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce, signing

I have been tasked to fix an old VB.NET project. I was successfully able to get all the forms loaded and the project running. When I try to deploy the project I get "default certificate could not be created. publish aborting." I also started VS.NET in admin mode and got the same errors. When I go to Properties > Signing > Sign the Click-Once manifest, I try to create a test Certificate and I get "error: The compute must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configure to allow delegation". I went into gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Security Settings > local policies > User Rights Assignment and have added my Administrator account to "Enable Computer Account and user account to be trusted for delegation" and added my admin account. I am still getting the same error. Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896769/c-sharp-2013-default-certificate-could-not-be-created-publish-aborting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 2013 Default certificate could not be created. Publish aborting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896769/c-sharp-2013-default-certificate-could-not-be-created-publish-aborting)

Comment: No it wont even let me create a certificate and I get "error: The compute must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configure to allow delegation".  Looks like a permissions issue but I'm logged in under the administrator account.  Is there a folder for the certs that I should check for access ?